# TS2554: typescript issue

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have some constructor like this.

```js
class SomeClass {
  min: number;
  start: any;
  end: any;
  widthMonth: number;

  constructor(wMonth: number, min: number, start: any, end: any) {
    this.min = min;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.widthMonth = wMonth;
  }

  /**
   * Format month number
   */
  formatMonth(num) {
    num = parseInt(num, 10);
    return num >= 10 ? num : '0' + num;
  };
  /**
   * Calculate starting offset for bubble
   */
  getStartOffset() {
    return (this.widthMonth / 12) * (12 * (this.start.getFullYear() - this.min) + this.start.getMonth());
  };

  /**
   * Get count of full years from start to end
   */
  getFullYears() {
    return ((this.end && this.end.getFullYear()) || this.start.getFullYear()) - this.start.getFullYear();
  };
}
```

And when i try to create object like this.

```
new SomeClass(widthMonth,min, start, end);
```

Typescript compiler throw this error.

**TS2350: Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword.**

**TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 4.**

Comment: What type are start and end? Change to correct type and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: I already said them type any, so there should not be any issue as long as u say any

Comment: Since the error is about "2 arguments, but got 4" it could be because the last 2 are declared as any. Declaring properties as `any` is just a lazy way in TS and you should invest some time into making everything type safe.

Comment: Can you include your definition of `SomeClass`?   Those errors imply that `SomeClass` is not being recognized as a function of two arguments, not as a class object whose `constructor()` method you have shown us.

Comment: @jcalz updated question take a look

Comment: [I still can't reproduce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Is the class definition in some other file from the call to `new SomeClass(...)`?  Maybe you're not importing the correct `SomeClass`.   Is there some other `SomeClass` declared in your code which is a function of two arguments?  Can you use [the PlayGround](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Include more information about the error you're facing please

Comment: Can't reproduce, seems like a non issue to me currently with TS 5.